# How to add values from outside of the producer class to producer thread(blocking queue implementation)

Tags: java, producer-consumer, blockingqueue

I want to add some strings from outside class to `sharedQueue`; what is the best practice to accomplish that?

1. Adding from outside class itself directly to `sharedQueue` and pass through constructor
2. Send that value to constructor and adding from there
3. Any other method?

If answer is 1 or 2 then why do all the examples show integer values putting in `run` method of producer and taking out in consumer method?

```
class Producer implements Runnable {

    private final BlockingQueue<String> sharedQueue;

    public Producer(BlockingQueue<String> sharedQueue) {
        this.sharedQueue = sharedQueue;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            sharedQueue.put("value passed from outside class");
        } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Producer.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: In markdown you can use 1. 9 (with a dot) to create a list, after a *doubl*e line ending. Code can nowadays be wrapped with three back-ticks (`\`\`\``) and inline code with single back-ticks (you can see my changes by clicking [here](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/59270441/revisions). In general do use question marks at the end of questions. Could you please take another look at the sentence before your code?

Comment: if the string that you want to put in the queue is not immediately available then you can pass the instance of the class which will have to string to the `Producer`. The *producer* then asks for the value from the class instance in a later point of time.